# How to use recursively to query get node after root one level (details see in the photo attach)?

Tags: sql

Category is organized by Tree in the following: When I know (Target1),How do I find (Source3) not root (after root one level
)?
[Details see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aprio.jpg)

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: First: Explain better the problem
Second: Show a better example
Third: Show us an example of code or pseudo-code you have tried to run

Comment: See details in attached file you will understand the problem I encountered.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. I have removed all those dbms tags, add one of them back - the one for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Have you tried having a look at [ask] and/or [mcve] before posting this question? If not, you should have done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE your_table ( source, target ) AS
  SELECT '0',     '1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0',     '2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0',     '3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1',     '1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1',     '1.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1',     '1.3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2',     '2.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2',     '2.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '3',     '3.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1',   '1.1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1',   '1.1.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1',   '1.1.3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1.2', '1.1.2.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1.2', '1.1.2.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.1.2', '1.1.2.3' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( target ) AS first_child
FROM   your_table
WHERE  target = '1.1.2.2'
START WITH source = '0'
CONNECT BY PRIOR target = source;
```

**Output**:

```
FIRST_CHILD
-----------
1
```